# Why fprintf doesn't work in thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, io, pthreads, stdout

I'm creating a thread with `pthread_create`.

Inside the thread function i use

```
fprintf(stdout, "text\n");
```

But this doesn't output anything to the console.  The same problem is with `printf`.
I've also tried to flush stdout buffer without any success. 
So the question is how to print anything to the console from a thread?

UPD:

```
void *listen_t(void *arg){
  fprintf(stdout, "test\n");
  fflush(stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  pthread_t tid;
  int err;

  err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &listen_t, &thread_params);
  if (err != 0){
    printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
  }
  else{
    printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The code from main works fine. But the thread doesn't output anything

Comment: Please show us a minimal complete example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Is the thread running detached? If so, then there is no STDOUT for it.

Comment: How do you pass `stdout` to the thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a call of `pthread_join`: if the main program exits before `printf`'s output gets to the console, you see nothing printed.

Adding `pthread_join(tid, NULL);` to your example fixes the output:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *listen_t(void *arg){
  fprintf(stdout, "test\n");
  fflush(stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  pthread_t tid;
  int err;

  err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &listen_t, NULL);
  if (err != 0){
    printf("\ncan't create thread :[%d]", strerror(err));
  }
  else{
    printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");
  }
  pthread_join(tid, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a note, you should use also mutex-lock here, and lock while printing to console (in case you're going to print with more than a single thread).

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi: stdio has internal locking. There is no need for another layer of locks.